How to extract specific metrics (mAP) from YOLOv7's train function?
I am using the train function from the file: https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/train_aux.py to train a YOLOv7 model on a custom dataset. I would like to optimize the hyperparameters (using Optuna) to get the optimal performance from the model.
I can generate different hyperparameters values using optuna.trial.Trial, import the correct train function, and call it with these hyperparameters. The point I get stuck at is extracting the mAP@@0.5:0.95 from the return value of the train function so I can return it from the objective function.
I tried using subprocess to call the train_aux.py file with different hyperparameters and regex to extract the mAP@@0.5:0.95 metric to optimize but it was the wrong way of doing this.
